# Try to show msgbox , but it's appear two times

Tags: autohotkey

```
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2
i =0
^Space::

PressKey := ! PressKey  ;Toggle PressKey True/False

Loop

{   if( ! PressKey)

        Break           ;If PressKey is False, stop pressing key

    
    SoundPlay, alarm.mp3 
    Sleep 3000      ;Delay between keypresses
    i++
}
MsgBox,   %i% times
return
```

when i run the code, and let's say sound played for 2 times and after that i stop the code by pressing the same hotkey.

msgbox appears but it appear 2 times and two different msgbox came out first msgbox is "2" and the other is  "3"

what i want is that show the count of sound play in msgbox , so if 5 time sound played than it show 5 and only once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey 2
i =0
^Space::

PressKey := ! PressKey  ;Toggle PressKey True/False
if !PressKey
    return

Loop

{   if( ! PressKey)

        Break           ;If PressKey is False, stop pressing key

    
    SoundBeep ; SoundPlay, alarm.mp3 
    Sleep 3000      ;Delay between keypresses
    i++
}
MsgBox,   %i% times
return
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).